# Vector within a multidimensional array - MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array, vector

In MATLAB, I want to declare a 4D matrix, where the last dimension can take two values (a 2-column vector is the last dimension). The trouble is, zeros(...) only accepts scalars, so I can't declare the vector within the matrix declaration. Any thoughts on how to do this?

i.e. in the below, how do I declare this array so that 'output' actually looks like `output=zeros(some_number,2)`;

```
beg=zeros(nsubj,nvids,nmark,output);
```

Comment: You want a 5D matrix not a 4D matrix. I give up after 3D!

Comment: Okay, I see. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In order to have the last dimension contain a 2-column vector, you need to define the 2 columns in the second dimension of your declaration like so:

`>> beg = zeros(4, 2, b, c);`

Here is the first 2-column vector of the last dimension:

```
>> beg(:,:,1,1)  

ans =

 0     0
 0     0
 0     0
 0     0
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: If that were the case then `A = zeros(4, 4, 4, 4);` and `A = zeros(4, 4, 4, 2);` would return 4 and 2 columns respectively for `A(:, :, 1)` but they don't they both return 4 columns.

Comment: Right, because in both of those cases, the 2nd dimension of your matrix has a length of 4. Look at my answer again... If you want a 2-column vector in ANY dimension, the 2nd entry in "zeros()", must be "2".

Comment: You haven't answered what is in the question though. You've given a 4D answer to a question that is actually looking for a 5D answer.

Comment: Ah - thank you so much for this. Like the commenter directly on my question, I suppose what I needed was a 5-D matrix, not 4D!

Comment: @skirmishdirmish: hhhmmm... I am a bit confused, it seems you want a 2D matrix (n-by-2) in the fourth dimension. This is nonsensical, i.e., this is not possible. However, it is possible to generate a n-by-2 matrix across 4 dimensions, which is what I have shown in the answer above.